# Sed substitute recursively

Tags: regex, sed

`echo ddayaynightday | sed 's/day//g'`

It ends up `daynight`

Is there anyway to make it substitute until no more match ?

Comment: Repeat until its length will stop changing. Don't know, how to do that in shell.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

My preferred form, for this case:

```
echo ddayaynightday | sed -e ':loop' -e 's/day//g' -e 't loop'
```

This is the same as everyone else's, except that it uses multiple -e commands to make the three lines and uses the `t` construct—which means "branch if you did a successful substitution"—to iterate.

Comment: Good to know how to enter multiple script lines on the command line in cases where ";" won't work. I'd prefer your answer also because of the `t` conditional jump which is clearer for me, as opposed to a pattern match with unconditional jump.

Comment: thanks :) i think this looks good, not sure if there is a better way using some extended regular ex..

Answer (score 8):

This might work for you:

```
echo ddayaynightday | sed ':a;s/day//g;ta'
night
```

Comment: It seems you need multiple `-e` switches

Answer (score 4):

The `g` flag deliberately doesn't re-match against the substituted portion of the string. What you'll need to do is a bit different. Try this:

```
echo ddayaynightday | sed $':begin\n/day/{ s///; bbegin\n}'
```

Due to BSD Sed's quirkiness the embedded newlines are required. If you're using GNU Sed you may be able to get away with

```
sed ':begin;/day/{ s///; bbegin }'
```

Comment: In sh-like shells you can also just insert a literal newline inside a quoted string.  On the other hand I find the `$'... string with escapes...'` construct prettier for short scripts like this anyway.  For really long scripts, using `-f file` is probably better.  In this particular case, multiple `-e` commands work too.

Comment: @torek: Good point about the multiple `-e` commands. I personally hate embedding newlines in a quoted string. It's typically harder to read and makes it much harder to share the command with other people (because commands are generally expected to be on one line).

Comment: thanks, your 2nd does not work on my osx, it just print out the input

Comment: @iKid: Yes, OS X has BSD sed, which is why you use the first version there.

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
$ echo ddayaynightday | sed ':loop;/day/{s///g;b loop}'
night
```

Depending on your system, the `;` may not work to separate commands, so you can use the following instead:

```
echo ddayaynightday | sed -e ':loop' -e '/day/{s///g
                                               b loop}'
```

Explanation:

```
:loop       # Create the label 'loop'
/day/{      # if the pattern space matches 'day'
  s///g     # remove all occurrence of 'day' from the pattern space
  b loop    # go back to the label 'loop'
}
```

If the `b loop` portion of the command is not executed, the current contents of the pattern space are printed and the next line is read.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It gives an error: `sed: 1: ":loop;/day/{s/day//g;b  ...": unused label 'loop;/day/{s/day//g;b loop}'`

Comment: @Graham - you're presumably using OS X or FreeBSD.  The script will work, but you need to break it into separate lines like F.J's "explanation".  You can only gang these commands up on a single line in GNU sed.

Comment: @Graham See my recent edit, I included a version that should work for you.

Comment: @torek - in non-GNU sed, the semicolon works as a command separator (i.e. between `s///g` and `b loop`), but not the other places, and newlines are required around curly braces.  IMHO this is one of the huge benefits of GNU sed over other variants.  Expands the capabilities of sed one-liners tremendously.  :)

Comment: thanks, they work on my linux box but not on my osx (both of them, 1st just print the input and 2nd unexpected EOF smth..)

Comment: @iKid - me too, exactly the same.  But like ghoti said, it works if you space things like like in the "Explanation" section.  Of course, you'll have to remove the comments too, because sed doesn't understand comments like that.

Answer (score 2):

with bash:

```
str=ddayaynightday
while true; do tmp=${str//day/}; [[ $tmp = $str ]] && break; str=$tmp; done
echo $str
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here they're: [while](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-while-loop/) and [strlen](http://bashrules.blogspot.com/2005/04/strlen-of-bash.html) in bash.
Using them one may implement my idea:

> Repeat until its length will stop changing.

There's neither way to set flag nor way to write such regex, to "substitute until no more match".