# Repeating regex replace with SED

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have the following lines (in reality there are ~1M of these lines):

```
foo|||bar
qux||boo|fzx
```

Note that every line contain exactly 4 fields, but the number of characters
can be more than 3.

What I want to do is to replace every`||` with `|nil|` resulting:

```
foo|nil|nil|bar
qux|nil|boo|fzx
```

What's the way to do it with sed?

I tried this but fail:

```
sed 's/||/|nil/g'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to repeat the substitution until it doesn't change:

```
sed ':a; s/||/|nil|/g; ta'
```

However this will not handle empty fields at the beginning or end, for that you need two more patterns:

```
sed 's/^|/nil|/; s/|$/|nil/; :a; s/||/|nil|/g; ta'
```

*Testing*

Input:

```
cat << EOF > infile
foo|||bar
qux||boo|fzx
|||
EOF
```

Run it:

```
<infile sed 's/^|/nil|/; s/|$/|nil/; :a; s/||/|nil|/g; ta'
```

Output:

```
foo|nil|nil|bar
qux|nil|boo|fzx
nil|nil|nil|nil
```

#### an awk way

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(length($i)==0) $i="nil" } 1' FS='|' OFS='|'
```

Comment: Doesn't exactly work on OS X. You have to break up each part as a new command as tore described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983646/sed-substitute-recursively. In this example use sed -e ':a' -e 's/||/|nil|/g' -e 'ta'.