# sed replace empty space with NULL

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Using sed

1. how can I replace \N with NULL
2. How can I replace the empty space || with NULL.

   ```
   |200|0||0|\N||^A|0|\N||
   ```

desired output

```
    |200|0|NULL|0|NULL|NULL|^A|0|NULL|NULL|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a slightly modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724643/repeating-regex-replace-with-sed). Something like this works with GNU sed:

```
sed ':a; s:|\(\\N\)\?|:|NULL|:g; ta'
```

Or more portable:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's:|\(\\N\)\?|:|NULL|:g' -e 'ta'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the command you are looking for might be called "tr". Try

```
tr \\n \\0
```

Comment: Best answer for the question in the title (though it doesn't answer the specific question in the description)

Comment: Wrong: this replaces each actual newline (not the string `\N`) with a null character (not the string `NULL`).  I think you misread the question!

Answer (score 0):

```
<file sed 's/\\N/NULL/g' | awk -F\| '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ if($i==""){ printf "|NULL"} else{  printf "|%s", $i}}; printf "|\n"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

with awk

```
awk 'gsub("\\\\N","NULL");gsub("\\|\\|","|NULL|")' temp.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

`sed -i 's/ /NULL/g'  temp.txt`

This will replace any space character with `NULL`.

Comment: Question was asking about an _empty_ column, not a column with a space (yes, you have to read carefully!).

Comment: No --- it will replace a space with "NULL", not the NULL character.