# How do I tell sed to repeat substitution until no match was replaced?

Tags: unix, sed

How do I tell sed to repeat substitution until no match was replaced?

If doing `echo x | sed 's/x/xx/g'` I'm really glad sed doesn't restart on the output.

But if I have, say, `echo 'x,a,b,x,x,c,x,d,e,x,x,x,f,x' | sed 's/,x,/,y,/g'`
it does not substitute every x for y, for an obvious reason: the prior substitution has already consumed the surrounding delimiters.

And I'm aware that I have a tiny problem with the first and last x as well, but I ignore this for simplicity of the question.

Edit: I have to clarify the question, as already mentioned but only in comments: I want to see every x replaced by y, but only if it was a single word for itself, enclosed by delimiters, commas in this example, but if there is a way to cope with more complex delimiters, this will be welcome.

(No way to fall into the y2k trap, replacing Monday by Mondak, just joking.)

Comment: You have different inputs and different substitutions. What is your goal?

Comment: @JohnGoofy I want to see y,a,b,y,y,c,y,d,e,y,y,y,f,y as an output, and no x replaced if there accidentally was an x inside a word, say ,abxcd, enclosed by the delimiters.

Comment: `echo 'x,x,x,x' | sed 's/,x,/,y,/g'` would be a simpler example. Do you want to replace all x? or just those within commas?

Comment: @hek2mgl only within the "delimiters", that happen to be commas. I don't want to transform Hoax into Hoay.

Comment: I think you are looking for `echo 'x,a,b,x,x,c,x,d,e,x,x,x,f,x' | sed ':a s/,x,/,y,/; ta'` this will effectively do recursive replacement until no more replacement is possible... to handle start/end as well, `sed -E ':a s/(^|,)x(,|$)/\1y\2/; ta'`

Comment: this kind of problem is more suited for regex with lookarounds: `echo 'x,a,b,x,x,c,x,d,e,x,x,x,f,x' | perl -pe 's/(^|,)\Kx(?=,|$)/y/g'`

Comment: @Sundeep *echo 'x,a,b,x,x,c,x,d,e,x,x,x,f,x' | sed ':a s/,x,/,y,/; ta'* is actually what i was looking for. I don't like to revoke an accepted answer (what's done is done), but if you make this into an answer I will at least upvote it.

Comment: I'd rather suggest to mark this question as duplicate then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983646/sed-substitute-recursively

Comment: @Sundeep looks reasonably close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\b` as a word delimiter.

```
$ echo 'x,xx,x,x' | sed 's/\bx\b/y/g'
y,xx,y,y
```

`\b` denotes word boundaries, but even used within a capture group it's not going to cause replacement of the characters outside the word, if any.

Comment: That's good, and close. I will only wait to see if there is a simple and more general way to do this even it the delimiters would not be commas but also word constituent characters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Most times people do not use characters that are in the `\w` set as delimiters because there are myriad words with those characters in them.

Comment: Exactly: "most times"

Comment: You could ask a different question if you have another.  You still haven't explained what you're looking for.   You need to define a set of delimiters AND valid word chars

Comment: @sundeep has a perl solution in the OP comments which would work for any arbitrary delimiter `(^|d) .. (d|$)` where `d` is the delimiter.  You'd just have the issue of splitting any word with `d` in it.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
$ echo 'x,a,b,x,x,c,x,d,e,x,x,x,f,x' | sed ':label; s/,x,/,y,/g; t label;'
x,a,b,y,y,c,y,d,e,y,y,y,f,x
```

? This will not replace the `x` at the edges but that was not requested explicitly.

It will also not replace `x` in words:

```
$ echo 'x,a,b,fix,x,c,x,d,e,x,x,x,f,x' | sed ':label; s/,x,/,y,/g; t label;'
x,a,b,fix,y,c,y,d,e,y,y,y,f,x
```

Explanation: the `t` command will jump to the label if some substition took place. It will the apply the same sed expression to the line again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ echo 'x,a,b,x,x,c,x,d,e,x,x,x,f,x' | sed 's/x/y/g'
y,a,b,y,y,c,y,d,e,y,y,y,f,y
```

Comment: OP requested that this not replace 'fix' with 'fiy'.